# Euler angles between 2 vectors (non standart)

Tags: c++, math, rotational-matrices, euler-angles

I have a task to calculate yaw, pitch and roll between 2 3d-vectors

***2 examples with same destination vector, but different source:***

```
1) First example:
Source vector: x=-626.264 y=-233.745 z=2270.071
Dest vector: x=-753.13 y=-1680.23 z=1881.34
Original rotation matrix 3x3:
   -0.082 -0.021 -0.996
   -0.964 -0.255 0.080
   -0.256 0.967 -0.000
Must be: yaw=1.655 pitch=-0.321 Roll=0.0

2) Second example:
Source vector: x=-168.809 y=-1121.165 z=1880.855
Dest vector: x=-753.13 y=-1680.23 z=1881.34
Original rotation matrix 3x3:
   -0.720 0.001 -0.694
   -0.694 0.001 0.720
   0.002 1.000 -0.000
Must be: yaw=2.375 pitch=0.0 (at the same height) Roll=0.0
```

***I've tried:***

1) Restoring original matrix and recalculating angles back:

```
pitch = -atan2f(-rot[1][2], rot[2][2]);
yaw = -atan2f(-rot[0][1], rot[0][0]);
```

edit: valid yaw, but inversed. pitch not valid, PI/2 all the time. roll invalid - must be always 0

2) Calculate angles from deltas:

```
yaw = atan2(delta.x, delta.y);
float padj = sqrt(pow(delta.x, 2) + pow(delta.x, 2)); 
pitch = atan2(padj, delta.z)
```

edit: valid yaw. pitch is dynamic, but not valid. roll is not calculated (like it must be)

**The trouble is nothing working right:**

1) roll *must be always null*

2) yaw is not problem anymore

3) pitch must be correct and be dependent on distance and z-axe difference, original value is *clamped between -1.484 and 1.134..*.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide first the Euler angle convention you are using in the format (example): (1) roll about x, (2) pitch about y, (3) yaw around z.

Comment: Also, what is the "original rotation matrix"?

Comment: Euler angles describe orientation of a *rigid body*, not of a vector.

Comment: Convention is: yaw right-left, pitch up-down, roll is not needen
Original rotation matrix is copy of matrix when all the angles right and valid
Thank you